# VSCode Restage Staged Files After Precommit Hooks Fail in order to Commit Again

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, pre-commit.com

I have a Django project with several pre-commit hooks with Python's `pre-commit` tool, configured as below:

```yaml
repos:
  - repo: https://github.com/pre-commit/pre-commit-hooks
    rev: v2.0.0
    hooks:
      - id: trailing-whitespace
      - id: end-of-file-fixer
      - id: check-yaml
      - id: check-added-large-files

  - repo: https://github.com/python/black
    rev: master
    hooks:
      - id: black
  - repo: https://github.com/asottile/seed-isort-config
    rev: master
    hooks:
      - id: seed-isort-config
  - repo: https://github.com/pre-commit/mirrors-isort
    rev: master
    hooks:
      - id: isort
  -   repo: https://gitlab.com/pycqa/flake8
      rev: master
      hooks:
      -   id: flake8
```

Normally, I do below when a commit fails due to pre-commit hooks on terminal:

```sh
git add foo.py
git commit -m "added foo"
# pre-commit runs and fails
# black, end-of-file-fixer fixes staged files
git add foo.py # add fixed files again
git commit -m "added foo"
# this time, runs successfully
```

I'd like to get the same behavior from VSCode.

[image: git panel of vscode]

I stage my changes, write commit message and commit. VSCode naturally fails.

[image: vscode fails on commit]

No matter how many times I commit on VSCode, it does not "stage" the automatic changes made by `black` and `end-of-file-fixer`. So, when I click again, I'd like VSCode to add the files again because their contents are updated. How can I do this?

Thanks in advance.

---

## Environment

- VSCode 1.52.1
- Git 2.25.1
- pre-commit 2.9.3

If relevant:

- Kubuntu 20.04.1
- Python 3.8

Comment: While this doesn't exactly solve your question, I recommend using Edamagit instead for a better Git interface in VS Code: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=kahole.magit